# Apps Script - get a timestamp from a cell containing a date and a cell containg a time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet containing 2 columns:

```
Date       | Time
01/01/2022 | 12:01
```

I would like to create a timestamp from the sheet in Google Apps Script without having to go through the creation of an additional column that would add A and B.

I have tried different ways, but I have not found something good enough.

Of course, when I do :

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ws = ss.getSheets()[0]
const date = ws.getRange(A2).getValue();
const time = ws.getRange(B2).getValue();

const timestamp = date + " " + time;
```

it is not working..

Any idea about an elegant way to work on that.
Thank you very much.

Florent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const timeStamp = ss.getRange("A2").getDisplayValue() + " " + ss.getRange("B2").getDisplayValue();
```

`getDisplayValue()` instead, so it gets each value as a `string`.

Comment: great! I have never checked the existence of this method for the ranges, it does the job perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi! Consider marking it as an accepted answer, so others know this solves it, should they face similar difficulties. Cheers,